# How to configure WSO2 to track usage per resource?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

I have published API with two GET methods.

1. /api/1/questions
2. /api/1/complaints

where /api/1 is a context. Currently DAS shows hits count for context. I want different stats for these two methods. Could you please help me to configure.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are getting in "API Usage by Resource Path" report in All Statistics in Publisher:

[image]

See https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Viewing+API+Statistics for details.

Comment: ri8. It shows same report for CONTEXT. I want it for path (Path after context. Already mentioned it in question). This report is for only API.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [JIRA](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-4869) for this issue, we will fix this in our next release.

Comment: The JIRA says, fix version is 2.0.0-Beta version. So If I download it from the link http://wso2.com/products/beta-releases/#wso2-api-manager-2.0.0-beta. Will it contain the above fix ? As it is updated on last friday. 
The same patch is available ? Because we are using wso2 1.9.0 in production. So upgrading it to 2.0.0 is bit risky as it is beta version. Let me know your thoughts over it.

Comment: @ManishKumar, there is a minor bug reported on Beta, and We have fixed it. We are hoping to release API Manager 2.0 RC pack this week. If you want to test, You can download the latest pack from our Jenkins daily build [here](https://wso2.org/jenkins/view/product-builds/job/product-apim/)